# How do you escape dot in dot syntax e.g. in get_json_object?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

I need to get the value of an attribute with a dot in it's name. I'm struggling to escape the dot.

```
get_json_object($"AColumn", "$.something.id")
```

I've tried "$.`something.id`", "$.['something.id']", "$.something`.id" and none of these seem to work.

Unfortunately, the [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#get_json_object-org.apache.spark.sql.Column-java.lang.String-) is very light.

Has anyone successfully done this before? Could anyone shed some light on the situation?

Comment: Please add some representative data and the code you have tried so far to your question. It's difficult to provide meaningful help without that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this-

### Load the test data

```scala
   val df = Seq(("p1", """{"a.id": 1, "b": 2}"""), ("p2", """{"a.id": 3}"""))
      .toDF("p_id", "p_meta")
    df.show(false)
    df.printSchema()
    /**
      * +----+-------------------+
      * |p_id|p_meta             |
      * +----+-------------------+
      * |p1  |{"a.id": 1, "b": 2}|
      * |p2  |{"a.id": 3}        |
      * +----+-------------------+
      *
      * root
      * |-- p_id: string (nullable = true)
      * |-- p_meta: string (nullable = true)
      */
```

### Use `get_json_object` as below

```scala
    df.withColumn("x", get_json_object($"p_meta", "$['a.id']"))
      .show(false)
    /**
      * +----+-------------------+---+
      * |p_id|p_meta             |x  |
      * +----+-------------------+---+
      * |p1  |{"a.id": 1, "b": 2}|1  |
      * |p2  |{"a.id": 3}        |3  |
      * +----+-------------------+---+
      */
```

### you can use `json_tuple` also

```scala
    df.withColumn("x", json_tuple($"p_meta", "a.id"))
      .show(false)
    /**
      * +----+-------------------+---+
      * |p_id|p_meta             |x  |
      * +----+-------------------+---+
      * |p1  |{"a.id": 1, "b": 2}|1  |
      * |p2  |{"a.id": 3}        |3  |
      * +----+-------------------+---+
      */
```

Comment: Having reviewed your answer it highlighted that I was using the reference incorrectly. I had get_json_object($"x", "$.['a.b']") when I switched to get_json_object($"x", "$['a.b']") it worked. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Instead of **`get_json_object()`** try with **json_tuple()** function.

**`Example:`**

```
df.show(false)
//+---------------------+
//|c                    |
//+---------------------+
//|{"id.i":1,"name":"a"}|
//+---------------------+

df.withColumn("gjo",json_tuple(col("c"),"id.i")).show(false)
//+---------------------+---+
//|c                    |gjo|
//+---------------------+---+
//|{"id.i":1,"name":"a"}|1  |
//+---------------------+---+

//we can keep multiple json keys    
sql("""select json_tuple(c,"id.i","name") from tmp""").show(false)
//+---+---+
//|c0 |c1 |
//+---+---+
//|1  |a  |
//+---+---+
```

**`Option2:`**

Use **`from_json()`** function to read json string using `StructType` schema.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val sch=new StructType().add("id.i",IntegerType).add("name",StringType)

df.withColumn("fj",from_json(col("c"),sch)).select("fj.*")show()
//+----+----+
//|id.i|name|
//+----+----+
//|   1|   a|
//+----+----+
```

Then you can **replace the column name** using **`.map`**, **`.toDF`**, **`.withColumnRenamed()`** functions.

Comment: I haven't tried this but thanks for taking the time to reply.