# Spark: nested json data and duplicate column names (pyspark)

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm dealing with deeply nested `json` `data`. My goal is to flatten the data. I know I can do this by  using the following notation in the case when the nested column I want is called `attributes.id`, where `id` is nested in the `attributes` column:

```
df = df.select('attributes.id')
```

The problem is that there is already a column in `df` called `id` and since spark only keeps the last part after `.` as the column name, I now have duplicated column names. What is the best way of dealing with this? Ideally the new column will be called `attributes_id` as to differentiate it from the `id` column.

Answer (score 0):

Rename the column using **`.withColumn`**

(or)

flatten the dataframe then use **`.toDF()`** to rename the columns in the dataframe.

**`Example:`**

```
#sample json file data
{"id":1,"attributes":{"id":10}}

spark.read.json("<json_file_path>").printSchema()
#root
# |-- attributes: struct (nullable = true)
# |    |-- id: long (nullable = true)
# |-- id: long (nullable = true)

spark.read.json("<json_file_path>").\
withColumn("attributes_id",col("attributes.id")).\
drop("attributes").\
show()
#+---+-------------+
#| id|attributes_id|
#+---+-------------+
#|  1|           10|
#+---+-------------+

#or using toDF
columns=['id','attributes_id']

spark.read.json("<json_file_path>").\
select("id","attributes.*").\
toDF(*columns).\
show()
#+---+-------------+
#| id|attributes_id|
#+---+-------------+
#|  1|           10|
#+---+-------------+
```

If you want to flatten dynamically then use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50156142) link answer.

Comment: Thanks, which one would be considered the best method? Or is there no real difference?

Comment: I think using `.withColumn()` gives you more control over which columns to be mapped.

Comment: Ok thanks. Would you know how to extract a nested field with a `.` in its name? For example, I'm trying to extract the field `Dr.Web` from `attributes.categories` from the data but due to the `.` in `Dr.Web` it gets confused and thinks `Dr` is a level in the json. I get the following error: `AnalysisException: No such struct field Dr in Dr.Web`

Comment: We need to escape it.. refer this link how to escape `.` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63341060/how-do-you-escape-dot-in-dot-syntax-e-g-in-get-json-object/63341706#63341706

Comment: Any idea how to do this for pyspark, the link was for scala?

Answer (score 0):

After the select you can `.alias("attributes_id")`